# android studio: having trouble setting global string array

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio

Hi I'm working on an android studio project using global arrays,
I can read from the global arrays fine, and have no problem writing 
to the global integers ,But i cannot figure out how to set the global 
array from code, this is the important parts of the project:

added this under application tag in the android manifest xml:

```
android:name=".Globals"
```

java class Globals:

```
import android.app.Application;

public class Globals extends Application {

public int empnum=13;
public int getData3() {
return empnum;
}
public void setData3(int empnum) {
this.empnum = empnum;
}

public String[] passw = {"0123","0123","0123","0123","0123","0123","0123","0123","0123","0123","0123","0123","0123"};
public String[] getData4() {
return passw;
}
public void setData4(String[] passw) {
this.passw = passw;
}

public int login=0;
public int getData5() {
return login;
}
public void setData5(int login) {
this.login = login;
}

public String[] empname = {"Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5","Name6","Name7","Name8","Name9","Name10","Name11","Name12","Name13","Not logged in"};
public String[] getData6() {
return empname;
}
public void setData6(String[] empname) {
    this.empname = empname;
}
```

Here is the block of code I'm having trouble with

inner class of java class TimeIn:

```
final Globals g = (Globals) getApplication();
final String[] empname = g.getData6();
final String[] passw = g.getData4();


public void onClick(View v) {

i = 0;
String empname = edit2.getText().toString();
int getemn = Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString());

    if (i == 0 && h == 0) {
        g.setData3(getemn);

        g.setData6(String[getemn], empname); // This one line right here won't compile, I have tried different combinations but have had 0 luck
    i = 1;
    h = 1;
        }
    }
```

I have no problems getting and using a String array, this is how it works to get 
an array value and compare it to a string:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

i = 0;
String getemp = edit2.getText().toString();
int getemn = Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString());


if (i == 0 && getemp.equals(passw[getemn])) { // All of this works perfectly
    g.setData3(getemn);
    g.setData5(0);
    tfone.setText("Empoyee " + getemn);
    tftwo.setText("Logged in");
    i = 1;
}
if (i == 0 && getemp != (passw[getemn])) {
    tfone.setText("No matches found");
    edit2.setText("Not logged in");
    i = 1;
}
```

}

So I know this line of code is wrong:

```
g.setData6(String[getemn], empname);
```

but for 
the life of me I can't figure out how it should be written, the only error hint is I
get from hovering over the line-

array type expected; found 'java.lang.String'

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: other things i tried with that line of code:                                 g.setData7(empname[getemn]);                             g.setData7([getemn]empname); + alot of other similar combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Global` class, you declare the method with one parameter

```
public void setData6(String[] empname) {
    this.empname = empname;
}
```

but when you call, you put 2 parameters `g.setData6(String[getemn], empname);`
You should remove one parameter
or add another method with 2 parameters in `Globals` class

**Also**
You are wrong in here

```
   ...
    String empname = edit2.getText().toString();
    int getemn = Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString());
    ...
    g.setData6(String[getemn], empname); // This one line right here won't compile, I have tried different combinations but have had 0 luck
```

The `setData6` function now require 2 parameters, one is `String array` and the other is `String`
but the way you put the `String array` to the function is wrong
Here is a simple example that show how to pass the `String array` to function

```
public class Test {
    public static void setData6(String[] empnameList, String empname) { // with the `String array` you should declare the variable name like `empnameList` or `arrEmpname` NOT `empname` because `empname` make confusing when you read code
        this.empnameList = empnameList;
        this.empname = empname;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strArray = new String[]{"Name1","Name2","Name2"};
        String empName = "Na";

        setData6(strArray,empName); // call method with 2 parameters here
    }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, adding another method with 2 parameters in Globals class must be what i need to do because im using 2 variables, getemn is an integer and should reference the "[]" part of the array, and the variable empname is what needs to be assigned to that part of the array, with the desired result being  empname[getemn]=getemp, so I'm pretty new to java, how would I write a 2 parameter method?

Comment: Hmmm, when i put what you said in my Global class :     public static void setData6(String[] empnameList, String empname) { 
        this.empnameList = empnameList;
        this.empname = empname;
    } I got errors like cannot resolve symbol empnameList, so i added public string[] empnameList above it to solve that, but then got the error array type expected; found 'java.lang.String' So I did some re arranging and the only way it's happy is if I do it this way

Comment: - public int setempn;
public void setData6(int empnameList, String[] empname) {
    this.empnameList= empnameList;
    this.empname = empname;
} and then call it from my TimeIn class with                             g.setData6(getemn, empname); This throws no errors but it doesnt change the array variable either. Im having a hard time understanding java arrays because im used to using arrays like this: you define the array empname[0]="Name1"; empname[1]="Name2"; next to use it you can just say empname[getemn]=getemp;

Comment: because the empnameList is not declare. you should declare it. i show you the idea, not full sourcecode

Comment: like i said i did declare it, that was easy to figure out but the error is still array type expected; found 'java.lang.String' unless you set that block of code as public void setData6(int empnameList, String[] empname) { this.empnameList= empnameList; this.empname = empname; }

Comment: you cant use static there either

Comment: Can i ask you this, in your code sentence: setData6(strArray,empName); is strArray the integer used in the brackets [] And is empName the string to use as the arrays value?

Comment: @Wraithious no. `strArray` is the `String array` and `empName` is the `String`

Comment: ok, now i know why I'm confused, i was trying to put an integer into the index of the array and set a string to the arrays value, so in java the index has to be fed in as a string?? I've been studying java for 2 months but java's use of arrays is throwing me for a complete loop, I'm going to take some more time studying arrays in java, my project is as good as done when I figure this out, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Solved!! it turns out I had to modify my setter part of my Globals class, so this first part (the getter method) in the Globals class is correct:

```
public String[] compname = {"Manager's company", "Company2", "Company3", "Company4", "Company5", "Company6", "Company7", "Company8", "Company9", "Company10", "Company11", "Company12", "Company13", "Not punched in"};
public String[] getData7() {
return compname;
}
```

I had to change the getter part of my Globals class to this:

```
public int setcmpn = 0; // <-- Edited, this should equal some integer value
public void setData7(int setcmpn, String compname) {  // removed [] from 2nd argument
this.setcmpn = setcmpn;
this.compname[setcmpn] = compname; // added in [] after array's name and fill it with the first argument from setData7 method
}
```

And to set the value of the desired index from any class just use:

```
Globals g = (Globals) getApplication();
g.setData7(getemn, getemp);
```

where getemn is an integer and getemp is a string.